# Using gulp-webserver with proxy and middleware

Tags: angularjs, proxy

I'm trying to get the gulp-webserver working with a proxy and middleware.

My angular app should run with gulp-webserver on port 3000
My Laravel backend runs on apache with URL: "http://backend.api/api/v1"

Now I would like to redirect/proxy all request in my angular app which starts with '/api' to 'backend.api/api/'

Example: url in angular for ajax: '/api/v1/users' should go to 'backend.api/api/v1/users' and get it's json data from there.

*sry for missing http in front of the backend.api url - but stackoverflow does not allow me more then 2 links in one post.*

I have tried may hours to get it working with gulp-webserver
On gulp-connect it was working with this setting:

```
gulp.task('webserver', function () {
    plugins.connect.server({
        root: paths.distDevelopFolder,
        port: 3000,
        middleware: function (connect, o) {
            return [(function () {
                var url = require('url');
                var proxy = require('proxy-middleware');
                var options = url.parse('http://backend.api/api');
                options.route = '/api';
                return proxy(options);
            })(), historyApiFallback];
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm using gulp-webserver like this:

```
var webserver = require("gulp-webserver")    
gulp.task('webserver', function(){
    return gulp
        .src([paths.distDevelopFolder])
        .pipe(webserver({
            port: 3000,
            livereload: true,
            open: 'http://localhost:3000',
            proxies: [
                {
                    source: '/api', target: 'http://backend.api/api'
                }
            ]
        }));
    });
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me I receive an error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED displayed in the browser whats that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this generator:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angular-proxy

It has exactly what you need (specify some URLs to be proxied to remote backend) and mock the rest.